# Open a new Site in angular

Tags: angularjs

I had a Single Page Application developed in angular-js and i need to open a printside under a new url. At present, printtext.html loads its content but on the inside of the index.html. What i want is to load the content of the printtext.html alone without any Content from the index.html. Basically if i click on the link in my index.html i just want to see in the browser the text `printtext`. And not something like `Some headertext` which is curretnly the case. Is that possible or do i break the SPA rules? My Main goal is to create a Printsite where i just see the content without any header or footer information. Or should i user ng-hide for this?
I am not including the logic here, but if required will provide.

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myapp">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Myapp</title>
    <script src="libs/js/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/js/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</head>

    <body>
    <h1> Some headertext </h1>
    <ng-view></ng-view>     
   </body>
```

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', ['ngRoute'])
    .config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/text', {
                templateUrl: "template/text.html"
            })
            .when('/print', { //actually the parameter is /print/:object but i left the logic out here
                templateUrl: "Print/printtext.html"
            })
    }])
```

text.html

```
<p> Some text </p>

<a ng-href="#!/print">Print </a> <!-- The right link would be something like #!/print/marc -->
```

printtext.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html ng-app="myapp">
<head><title>
    Printview
</title>

    <script src="../libs/js/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="../libs/js/angular-route.js"></script>

    <script src="../js/app.js"></script>
<body>

        <p>printtext</p> 

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You directly use `target = "_blank"` in your anchor tag.

```
<p> Some text </p>

    <a ng-href="#!/print" target="_blank">Print </a> <!-- The right link would be something like #!/print/marc -->
```

Otherwise, you can create a dynamically custom directive in angular.
custom directive generally uses to set target according to a dynamic condition.

```
<p> Some text </p>

<a ng-href="#!/print" ng-attr-target="_blank">Print </a> <!-- The right link would be something like #!/print/marc -->
```

---

```
<a ng-attr-target="_blank">
  ...
</a>
```

ng-attr-xyz lets you dynamically create @xyz, and if the value is undefined no attribute is created.

Comment: For me it opens up a new site but with the same result. But i will check if i can do something with the ng-attr-target attribute.

Comment: `load the printsite on a new url?` you want to load printsite page on new tab or under or in same page.

Comment: i updated my question hope that its now understandable.